# Video face detection frame sampling

Tags: opencv, image-processing, face-detection

I am using OpenCV python to detect faces in a video(30fps). The problem is my code runs detection algorithm for each frame in the video, which is slow and inefficient. Is there any way to sample only a few frames from the video that speeds up this process?

Comment: yes, just skip the frames by using the command "continue". Share your code so that we can help you guide you to what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can use the frame count to determine if process current frame. Below code for your reference.

```
if frame_count % 5 == 0:
    face_detect(frame)
else:
    continue
```